# Addition with while loop in java

Tags: java, addition

I'm trying to figure out how to create a java program where the user inputs a series of integers, the last integer being a 0 (when the program should stop).  After stopping, the program should print out the sum of the integers.  This needs to be done using a while (true) loop with an if statement

```
if (num == 0) {
    break;
}
```

With everything I have tried so far, the loop will not stop even when 0 is inputted.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare a sum variable

2) Start a infinite loop

3) Read user input

4) Add it to sum variable

5) If the user input is 0 break out of the loop and print the value of sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Statictest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);   
        while (true) {
            int temp = scn.nextInt();
            if (temp == 0) {
                break;
            }
            sum += temp;
        }   
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }
}
```